# Calculate how many hours from datetime and day of week name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help on my SQL. How can I can add day of the week and calculate how many hours were worked on that day.

```
    SELECT CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp) AS DATE
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])AS StartTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])AS EndTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])+ CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])
  FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
```

Comment: Monday, Tuesday,Wednesday etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN MSSQL, this should work

```
   SELECT CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp) AS DATE
      , datename(dw,CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp)) as dayOfWeek
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])AS StartTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])AS EndTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])+ CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])
  FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
```

Comment: You can also use weekday  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008

Comment: one thing i want to ask how I can combine Date and dateOfWeek in one column

Comment: ask in another question. but it sounds like you want to do something for a report to a customer, I would do that in a report builder.

Comment: I agree this should be a separate question but since dateName is a varchar you could convert your date to a varchar and just concatenate the two strings

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467872/how-to-combine-two-data-columns#comment16770982_12467872