# how to combine two Data Columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have this SQL statement I want to combine 'date' and 'dayOfWeek' Column

```
 SELECT CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp) AS DATE
      , datename(dw,CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp)) as dayOfWeek
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])AS StartTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])AS EndTime
      ,DATEDIFF(HH,[startTimeStamp] ,[endTimeStamp])
  FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
```

Comment: combine them how? in the same column?

Comment: You can `CONCATENATE` them after you convert/cast them to strings.

Comment: What's in the two columns you want to combine and what's the end result supposed to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp) AS DATE
      , datename(dw,CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp)) as dayOfWeek
      ,cast(datename(dw,CONVERT(date, startTimeStamp)) as varchar(50)) -- add this
        + ' ' +                                                     -- add this
        CONVERT(varchar(50),CONVERT(date,startTimeStamp)) FullDate -- add this
      ,CONVERT(time,[startTimeStamp])AS StartTime
      ,CONVERT(time,[endTimeStamp])AS EndTime
      ,DATEDIFF(HH,[startTimeStamp] ,[endTimeStamp])
  FROM [TaskManagementSystem_DB].[dbo].[Timesheet_entry]
```

To concatenate the fields together you must `cast()` them to the same datatype, similar to this:

```
select cast(datename(dw,CONVERT(date, getdate())) as varchar(50)) 
  + ' ' +
  CONVERT(varchar(50) ,getdate()) newdate
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f5cf/6)