# SQL Server 2008 Count(Distinct?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ApptStart
2005-02-18 10:00:00.000
2005-02-18 13:00:00.000
2005-02-18 11:00:00.000
2005-02-21 09:00:00.000
2005-02-18 15:30:00.000
2005-02-18 14:30:00.000
.
.
.
```

I have a column in our database that looks like the above. I want to count appointments for the month for a given doc. On Fridays most of them do a half day. So I do not want to count Fridays with appointments only in the morning. If the appointment is in the afternoon, after 12:00:00.000 I want to include that day in the distinct count.

So far I have:

```
SELECT
   ScheduleDays = count(distinct CONVERT(datetime, convert(char(12), a.ApptStart, 1)))
FROM Appointments a
WHERE   
    ApptKind = 1 AND 
    --filter on current month
    a.ApptStart >= ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0),'1/1/1900') AND
    a.ApptStart < ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0),'1/1/3000') AND
    --Filter on doctor
    a.ResourceID in (201)
```

This worked when I counted every day with appointments on it, but like I said I need to exclude those half days.So I was thinking about only looking at the last right chars of the `ApptStart` and comparing it x > noon in a case inside the distinct count...

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
ScheduleDays = count(distinct case when (Right(a.ApptStart, 12)) > '12:00:00:000' then 1 else 0 END)
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
I tried:

```
SELECT  
ScheduleDays=COUNT(DISTINCT(CAST(datediff(d,0,a.ApptStart) as datetime)))
FROM Appointments a
WHERE   
ApptKind = 1 AND 
--filter on current month
a.ApptStart >= ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0),'1/1/1900') AND
a.ApptStart < ISNULL(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())+1, 0),'1/1/3000')AND
--filter all days that aren't Friday, and then give you all Fridays with an hour > 12.
 DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) <> 'Friday' OR DATEPART(hour, a.ApptStart) > 12 AND
--Filter on doctor
a.ResourceID in (201)
```

for 1808 as the count

Comment: What do you mean when you say your code "didn't work"?  What results did you get?  Or did you get an error?

Comment: I mean that it only returned 1 appointment.. it should have been less than 16 for that particulair doc for this month as 16 was the count before I tried to get rid of the friday half days.    EDIT I just counted it should return 12.

Comment: You are counting the unique results of a case statements whose only results can be 1 or 0, the count then can only be in the range 0 to 2.

Comment: Can you give your question a better, more descriptive title? It looks like a question that could be of use to other users, so would be a shame if it will not be found by them because of the title :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to treat dates as dates, rather than strings.  You can determine whether a particular timestamp is on a Friday -- or the hour of a timestamp -- using `DATEPART`, without having to CONVERT it into a CHAR:

---

`datename(weekday, timestamp_value)` -- returns Friday

`datepart(weekday, timestamp_value)` -- returns either 5 or 6, depending on the value of `SET DATEFIRST`.  ([Get day of week in SQL 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008))

`datepart(hour, timestamp_value)` -- returns hour part

---

Using these, you can test whether a timestamp is on Friday at or after noon by checking if `datepart(weekday, timestamp_value)` = 6 and `datepart(hour, timestamp_value)` >= 12.

bendataclear pointed out that you're using distinct on a case statement which can only ever return 0 or 1, so your total will only ever be 0, 1, or 2. If you're trying to determine which days the doctors worked more than half a day, you'll need to select distinct dates --

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CAST(datediff(d,0,timestamp_value) as datetime)))
FROM table_name 
WHERE DATENAME(weekday, timestamp_value) <> 'Friday' OR DATEPART(hour, timestamp_value) > 12
AND the rest of your filters here
```

The WHERE clause there will give you all days that aren't Friday, and then give you all Fridays that have an hour > 12.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I believe I almost have it; that datepart is going to be very useful. What should I use instead of "then 1 else 0?"

Comment: Oh!  That might be part of the problem too!  @bendataclear above pointed out that you're using distinct on a case statement which can only ever return 0 or 1, so your total will only ever be 0, 1, or 2.  If you're trying to determine which days the doctors worked more than half a day, you could just do a distinct on the date itself -- SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(CAST(datediff(d,0,timestamp_value) as datetime)).  I've edited the answer to accommodate.

Comment: I tried the following and received 1808.. whoops I did something wrong. --filter on half days and fridays
DATENAME(weekday, a.ApptStart) <> 'Friday' OR DATEPART(hour, a.ApptStart) > 12

Comment: Did you remember to include your original filters?

Comment: Oh I figured it out; changed the or to and on the filter you helped with. Jim thank you so much for your help! I would vote up your answer, but I just registerd and have no rep points. This was a great resource : )

Comment: No problem!  Go ahead and click the check mark to accept the answer if it got you where you needed to go.