# How to get first day of the week and last day of the week in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

How to get the first day of the week and last day of the week when we input any one day of a week?

For example if we enter a date then the first(Monday) and last (Friday) day should be displayed. 
that is if we enter 24-jan-2014 then 20-jan-2014 and 24-jan-2014 should be displayed.

Regards

Comment: Maybe this Q can helpyou: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168874/get-first-day-of-week-in-sql-server

Comment: And this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008

Comment: What should be returned for 25-jan-2014?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
DECLARE @yourdate date = getdate()
Select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, @yourdate), 0)
Select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, @yourdate), 4)
```

You set `@yourdate` to the date you want. The first SELECT will give you the first day and the second SELECT will give you the last date

Comment: Your 4 must change to 7 to get the 7th day of the week

Comment: @Pierre I think he meant work week and not regular week. Although if he had meant a regular week you'd have to change it to 6 to get Sunday.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you! :)

Comment: This does not wrap around years, try 
select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, convert(date, '01 January 2017')), 0)

Comment: Also remember that DATEDIFF(wk) is based on Sunday's only.  See the following MS link for proof of that.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql#remarks

Answer (score 3):

This solves it and also wraps around year ends:

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(d, 0, '01 January 2017') / 7, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '5/13/2005'), 6)
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '5/13/2005'), 5)
```

**(Or)**

```
Declare @Date datetime
Det @Date = '2012-04-12'
Delect @Date - DATEPART(dw, @Date) + 1 FirstDateOfWeek,
       @Date + (7 - DATEPART(dw, @Date)) LastDateOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

With a calendar date already loaded, group can be done like this for all the years existing in the table =)

```
select 
Y,
M,
(Select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, dt), 0) ) wk_str_dt ,
(Select dateadd(ww, datediff(ww, 0, dt), 4)  )wk_end_dt , 
dt recd_crt_dt
from [tcalendar]
where  isWeekday= 1 
AND DW = 2 -- only mondays
order by Y, W
```