# how to find the weekend dates from given list of dates

Tags: sql, isqlquery

I have a list of dates and  other columns in which have to find the weekend dates among them and the the weekend dates should be there in the list of given dates

[image]

Output should be some thing like this...

[image]

Any help is appricated  thanks.

Comment: You can use datename as explained here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate.  However, if the question has internationalization issues, then the duplicate is not appropriate (the question doesn't mention these, however).

Comment: plz read my question ....the link you hv given is not my requirement

Comment: i want weekend dates from given list, the resultent dates should be ther in the list

Answer (score 0):

use `datepart (dw,..`
to filter data needed

Comment: i hv tried this 
select DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, #t.Date1)), Date1) as WEEKENDDAY from #t group by DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, #t.Date1)), #t.Date1)

Comment: output is :2014-04-12 00:00:00.000
2014-04-19 00:00:00.000

Comment: can u help me with the example

Comment: @mvinay I just realize '2014-04-09' and '2014-04-16' are not weekends and you put them as desired output.  I'm afraid I misunderstood your request. Could you check if '2014-04-12' and '2014-04-13' should be the right output?

Comment: ya these two dates are not weekends but they are the last dates in the given dates list

Comment: @mvinay I wanna help you, but I don't undestand your request. Please edit your question with other words and examples.