# SQL Server determining the day from an existing date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to determine what day a date is by looking at a column date. Is it possible, and if so, how do you look at a column date/reference the column, and determine which day it is?

Current results:

[image]

Desired results:

[image]

Code for testing:

```
 CREATE TABLE #Date 
 (
     IncidentDate DATE,
     [Day] VARCHAR(10)
 )

 INSERT INTO #Date (IncidentDate)
 VALUES ('20170803'), ('20170817'), ('20170831'), ('20170901'),
        ('20170905'), ('20170914'), ('20170908'), ('20170914'), 
        ('20171010'), ('20171020'), ('20171024'), ('20171027'),
        ('20171026'), ('20171024'), ('20171102'), ('20171106')

SELECT *
FROM #Date
```

Comment: Use datename. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql

Comment: Since every single answer at this point is using the date shortcuts I would suggest you read this article. Those shortcuts are painful to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: That blog link was redirected to this link. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations  Thank you Sean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DATENAME function will return the name of the date.

Using your above data:

```
 SELECT   *
        , DATENAME(dw, IncidentDate) [DayOfWeek]
 FROM #Date
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **datename** function in sqlserver.

```
  SELECT DATENAME(dw,'2018/04/13');

  Answer: Friday
```

Trivia: Today is friday the 13th.

Comment: Can I get the day without having to code the date, can I reference the column IncidentDate?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

you can use DATENAME in building the table - note the conversion of the string first.

```
CREATE TABLE #Date (
 IncidentDate DATE,
 [Day] varchar(10)
 )

 INSERT INTO #Date
 (
     IncidentDate,
     Day
 )
 VALUES
 ('20170803', DATENAME(dw,CONVERT(CHAR(10), '20170803', 120)))


 SELECT *
 FROM #Date
```

outout

```
IncidentDate    Day
2017-08-03      Thursday
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `DATENAME`, like so...

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, IncidentDate)
FROM #Date
```

The first input of the function `dw` can vary, based on the date part that you want to get out of the date (month, day, quarter, year, etc...)

More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql)

Answer (score 1):

you mean something like this

```
 SELECT IncidentDate,DATENAME(dw,IncidentDate)
 FROM #Date
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/940e6/4)

Explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1113891/2572645)