# Return day number for the date passed

Tags: sql-server

How can we find the day number for a date passed. Say, if it is 'Sunday', then 1, 'Monday', then 2 and so on. Is there any in built function for this other than user defined functions?

Comment: Please have some date type queries and check samples. if getting struck somewhere, provide the queries used and their bottlenecks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `DAYOFWEEK`. The format is:

```
 SELECT{fn DAYOFWEEK(GETDATE())}
```

Alternate method:

```
 SELECT DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server builtin function [`DATEPART()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) takes two parameters and can do what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW , GETDATE() -1)   -- Returns 1 for sunday.
```

Also depending on what you pass to the 1st parameters in the function, it can return different parts of the date value passed in the second parameter.

Comment: Actually, this one returns 1 for Monday. You could avoid the `-1` part right?

Comment: @AsRa I have used `-1` is to get Sunday's date not to get 1, I have passed GETDATE() which will pass the function today's date, I wanted to passed the functino Sunday's date.