# Get the weekday from a datecolumn

Tags: sql, date

I have following column:

```
Time: 2019-01-10 07:31:27.000
  ...
```

Now I want the weekday for each row.

So for example for the first row
I want as a result
Sunday

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Zaynul

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get day of week in SQL 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-2005-2008)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try this (MS SQL):

```
select datename(weekday,[yourDateTimeColumn]) from [YourTable]
```