# Select records where time not monday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I'd like to create a select statement with the following pseudocode:

```
select * from temperatures
where tm != monday
```

tm is a `datetime` field.

Comment: Simply read the manual to find the function to get the day of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DAYOFWEEK()`:

```
select * 
from temperatures
where datepart(weekday, tm) <> 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 select * from temperatures
    where DATEPART(WEEKDAY, tm) != 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this answers your quastion
[Get day of week in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-server-2005-2008)

in your case

```
select * from temperatures
where DATENAME(dw,tm) != 'monday';
```