# Using case statement to exclude the weekend with dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to set a reminder date for at least 3 days before a certain date(sample-date). If that date is set on Tuesday or Wednesdays the reminder date will be set to be sent on Saturday and Sunday. I thought about setting the reminder date for Tuesdays 4 days in advance and for Wednesday 5 days in advance. This way all of my reminders will be sent during the week. I thought about using the `dateadd` with the case statement but not sure how to incorporate certain weekdays within my `datedd` function.

```sql
select dateadd (day,-3,convert(char(10),sample_date,101)) as Reminder_Sent 

-- Ideally, my query should look like something like the below: 

select 

case when dateadd (monday,-3,convert(char(10),sample_date,101)) as Monday_Reminder_Sent
when dateadd (Tuesday,-4,convert(char(10),sample_date,101)) as Tuesday_Reminder_Sent
When dateadd (Wednesday,-5,convert(char(10),sample_date,101)) as Wednesday_Reminder_Sent
when dateadd (Thursday,-3,convert(char(10),sample_date,101)) as Thursday_Reminder_Sent
Else as Reminder_Sent
End
```

Comment: `dateadd (monday`? `monday` isn't a valid first parameter for `DATEADD`. Also, that is a `CASE` **expression**, not a `Case` (`Switch`) statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get day of week in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-server-2005-2008)

Comment: That's right. It's not a valid statement. I wanted to show what I am looking to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use datename for comparison. Looking at your logic you will have a different calculation only for tuesday and wednesday, in which case it should return a friday instead of the weekend.  All other days you need to go back 3 days.

```
declare  @sample_date     datetime 
set @sample_date = getdate()

select @sample_date as date , case   DATENAME ( weekday,@sample_date ) 
                when 'Tuesday' then dateadd (day,-4,convert(char(10),@sample_date ,101))
                when 'Wednesday' then dateadd (day,-5,convert(char(10),@sample_date ,101))
            else dateadd (day,-3,convert(char(10),@sample_date,101)) 
            end as Reminder_Sent
```

You could use DATEPART as well. But you will have to SET DATEFIRST first.