# How to return data for specific day names from date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, filter

Imagine I have a SQL Server table as shown below, named `dbo.tblNAV`:

```
Ticker   ISIN          Date         Price
------------------------------------------
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-09   45454
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-10   45455
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-11   45456
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-12   45457
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-13   45458
TSLA     US88160R1014  2021-08-16   45459
```

How can I select the data only for Mondays and Fridays?

I am a beginner in SQL Server and almost have no idea to handle this. I would appreciate your help.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Please show your research and attempt.

Comment: Does this any your question? [Get day of week in SQL Server 2005/2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110998/get-day-of-week-in-sql-server-2005-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does not make this easy to do across all systems.  The problems are:

- `datename()` returns the name of the week, but the language depends on local culture settings.
- `datepart()` returns the day of week number, but the start of the week depends on local settings.

If you are working in English, then you can use `datename()`:

```
where datename(weekday, n.date) in ('Monday', 'Friday')
```

If you need a culture-independent method, then you can use `format()` with a culture argument:

```
where format(n.date, 'ddd', 'us-en') in ('Mon', 'Fri')
```

Comment: For language agnostic, what about `(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, n.date) % 7) IN (0, 4)`?

Comment: @MatBailie . . . I'm not really a fan of assuming the day-of-the-week of date `0`, but that would also work.

Comment: Then just pick a more recent and known reference point? Such as 2000-01-01? (That's a Saturday. So, `IN (3, 6)`, or just find any Monday to base from?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something called DATENAME(interval, date) -> more on that [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datename.asp) which will return name of a day.
Function may be called DAYNAME in some DBs like [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.01/en-US/20e115c375191014a259acd3d72e3722.html)

I.E.

```
SELECT DAYNAME ('2011-05-30') "dayname" FROM DUMMY;
```

will return "Monday"

Comment: Assumes the system is in English. Local settings may be different, or may even change.