# How to replace an int with text in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query, which returns  days of the week. The days of the week are 0-6(Mon-Fri).

```
select ID, DayOfWeek from MyTable

ID    DayOfWeek
1     0
2     0
3     4
```

Is there a way to substitute an alias for each int DayOfWeek? The enum isn't stored in the database so I can't join.

I want to be able to write a query and have it look like this:

```
ID    DayOfWeek
1     Monday
2     Monday
3     Friday
```

Comment: Why can't the enum be stored in the database?

Comment: This is the opposite question, but the solutions still apply:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387434/converting-the-name-of-a-day-to-its-integer-representation

Comment: You should have a lookup table in your database for this. If you need it as an enum, it can be autogenerated using some templating mechanism (for example T4).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should consider storing the lookup in a new table... but just so you're aware of your options, you can also use the [`DATENAME(WEEKDAY)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function:

```
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, 0)
```

Returns:

```
Monday
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ca74/2)

Comment: Curious. Why does this return monday?

Comment: Answered my own question. Apparently `0` is `January, 01 1900 00:00:00+0000`, which just *happens* to be a Monday. Love it.

Comment: @lc. Dumb luck.  `CAST(0 AS DATETIME)` is January 1st, 1900... which happened to be a Monday.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't store a table to join on, you can use a `CASE`:

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE DayOfWeek
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Monday'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Tuesday'
        ...
    END AS DayOfWeek
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following:

```
SELECT ID, DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, DayOfWeek, CAST('2013-08-05' AS date)))
FROM MyTable
```

The logic is:

1. Take a date you're sure is Monday (`'2013-08-05'` is)
2. Add `DayOfWeek` days to that date
3. Take `DATENAME(dw)` from that date

***Edit***

Or even simpler way: `DATENAME(dw, DayOfWeek)`: [**Live demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/6280)

Answer (score 1):

```
datename(weekday, DayOfWeek)
```

should translate the int to a name.